# how to get data from json using python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

So basically I have following json  response from which I'm trying to get 1 piece of data in a for loop
Here is the json response

```
{
    "RecommendSoftwareImageTypeDTOList": {
        "id": "imageReferenceType",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "imageFileName",
                "imageReferenceName": "RELEASE",
                "imageReferenceType": "SYSTEM_SW",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "deviceId": 74519445,
                        "deviceName": "kyc4200-120.20.20",
                        "features": "NA",
                        "imageChecksums": "fedc49ad67ae66702d55fcce51439b06",
                        "imageFamily": "kyc4200",
                        "imageFileName": "kyc4202-universalk9.17.09.02a.SPA.bin",
                        "imageName": "kyc4202-universalk9.17.09.02a.SPA.bin", #this is the data I want to get
                        "imageType": "RELEASE",
                        "inRepository": "Yes",
                        "ipAddress": "10.104.120.20",
                        "result": "Success",
                        "size": 536558675,
                        "version": "17.09.02"
                    }
                ],
                "resultErrMsg": "",
                "totalCount": 1
            }
        ],
        "totalCount": 1
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the value of `imageName` in a for loop because there might be more items in the array `items`

Here is the code I'm using,

```
            if response.status_code == 200:
                if "RecommendSoftwareImageTypeDTOList" in response.text:
                    if "items" in response.text:
                        image_data = response.json()
                        image_list = image_data['RecommendSoftwareImageTypeDTOList']
                        image_list = image_list['items']
                        for i in image_list:
                            inactive_images.append(i['imageName'])
                            print(active_images)
```

I'm still getting error, can you help to get the data without error, here is the output I get.

```
: Response code: 200
: 'imageName'
:Traceback (most recent call last):
:   File "/tyu_suite.py", line 189, in Get_xe_images_api
:     inactive_images.append(i['imageName'])
: KeyError: 'imageName'
```

Comment: `imageName` is a key inside of `items` which itself is a key inside of `items`. So `image_list = image_list['items'][0]['items]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to retrieve the image names:

```py
images = response_text.get('RecommendSoftwareImageTypeDTOList', {})
for outer_item in images.get("items", {}):
    for inner_item in outer_item.get("items", {}):
        inactive_images.append(inner_item['imageName'])
```

- This solution does not have any `if` statement in it because it uses `dict.get()`
- The expression `response.text.get('RecommendSoftwareImageTypeDTOList', {})` says if RecommendSoftwareImageTypeDTOList is in the dictionary, get its value. If not, return an empty dictionary.
- Likewise, the two `.get("items", {})` expressions does the same: return the values for "items" or return an empty dictionary.